# Multiple file attachment for a model in a same form (nested form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model (say 'X') which can have many submodel (say model 'Y', where 'Y' has has a title, description and a file attachment). I have implemented Y with paperclip for file attachment. How do I create a form for model 'X' which contains a form for the sub model 'Y' and is inside the form 'X', moreover i need to be able to associate multiple 'Y' objects with 'X' (like attaching multiple files in a mail in gmail or yahoo)? Is there any gem for this purpose?

Thanks,
RoR n00b.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a simple example of what you're looking for, and in the example I've changed your 'X' model to 'Foo' and 'Y' to 'Bar'.

Model:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @foo do |foo_form| %>
  <%= foo_form.text_field :blah %>
  ...
  <%= fields_for @foo.bars do |bar_fields| %>
    <%= bar_fields.file_field :photo%>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it possible to submit this form alone "  <%= fields_for @foo.bars do |bar_fields| %>
    <%= bar_fields.file_field :photo%>
    ...
  <% end %>" Actually I need a "Add" and a "cancel" button for foo and bar separately.. Is that possible with this form?

Comment: Well this will have only one submit button right, and if we submit everything will be posted for foo and bar right?! but i want to update bar model alone keeping the user in the same page..